# How to get the url parameter in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Here's my url

`localhost/project/#/showprofile/18`

I want to display the parameter `18` in my view

In the `app.js` i have

```
.when('/showprofile/:UserID', {
     title: 'Show User Profile',
     templateUrl: 'views/layout/showprofile.php',
     controller: 'authCtrl',
     })
```

**Here the page `showprofile.php` is displaying, but suddenly the url goes like this**

`localhost/project/#/showprofile/:UserId`

**How can i get the value `18` inside the `showprofile.php` and make the url as it is i.e.,**

`localhost/project/#/showprofile/18`

Comment: you will get the user id with this $routeParams.UserID. pass it to the controller and assign it to a variable and you can use it in the tamplate

Answer (score 2):

Use `$routeParams` to get the parameter value:

```
$routeParams.UserID
```

Make sure you inject `$routeParams` before using it.

**EDIT**
*How can i get the value 18 inside the showprofile.php*

```
<?php
    $link = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; // Get current URL
    $link_array = explode('/', $link); // Split by /
    echo $page = end($link_array); // Get last element from array

?>
```

Comment: What might be reason for redirection to `localhost/project/#/showprofile/:UserId` this ?

Comment: I am not sure about `inject` whenever i click the link i am getting redirected to the above url, is there any problem in my route ?

Comment: Thanks for the update, but ii don't know the reason for the immediate redirection to here after i click the link `localhost/project/#/showprofile/:UserId`

Comment: @user4989228 It is what you've told to do, by creating a route

Comment: I should have like this ? `.when('/showprofile/$routeParams.UserID', {` ? I am getting error in console like this **TypeError: Cannot read property '$$route' of undefined**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$location.path()`.

As an example,

```
if ($location.path() === 'localhost/project/#/showprofile/18' 
{
// logic goes here
}
```

You need to inject `$location`

Comment: You mean instead of `.when` i want to use the given `if` condition ?

Comment: you can use .when and not necessary if.. but the point is $location.path() gives url value.

Comment: But how can i fix the url redirection to this ? `localhost/project/#/showprofile/:UserId`

Comment: Your question title: How to get the url param in angular js? please correct the title.

Answer (score -1):

You can use jquery to get value.

```
var parts = window.location.pathname.split('/');
var id = parts[parts.length - 1];
```

Comment: But i said i my url is getting redirected to this `localhost/project/#/showprofile/:UserId` :(

Comment: Your quesion: How to get the url param in angular js?

Comment: Ok, but i have stated that i am getting redirected to the above given url ! If i use the one you have given i will always get `:UserId` as my result